# Pilot's license for ENFP?

Tags: pilots

I'm an ENFP and really interested in getting my private pilot's license. I was wondering - are there ay other ENFP pilots out there? If so, do you like being a pilot? I'm afraid I might get bored with it, as things get rather routine for me fairly quickly. Is it a job that involves people/creativity would you say? Thanks! =)

Comment: "Flying is hours and hours of boredom sprinkled with a few seconds of sheer terror."

Comment: Enlighten this nearly 80 year old. What is ENFP?

Comment: @Terry Personality type. https://www.16personalities.com/enfp-careers

Comment: It’s a personality type Terry.  https://www.16personalities.com/enfp-personality

Comment: @Pilothead - Hooray, humans can be categorized into 16 things, [nothing wrong with that whatsoever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers–Briggs_Type_Indicator#Criticism), it's even 4 more than the other system. Joking aside, dear Belle, don't limit your future by what some website claims to be true about you.

Comment: @ymb1 So personality disorders correlate with INTP? I think I have one of those laying around.)

Comment: I highly encourage everyone to read this page: http://www.code7700.com/psychology_101.htm#pilotpersonalitytypes .

Comment: I also encourage everyone, in the nicest way I can, to appreciate that not all people who fit into the same category perform in the same way or have the same interests...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It looks like your question has been closed because this site isn't a good fit for it. Keep in mind that we don't think it's a *bad question*, but this site is designed to handle factual questions that have a single "right answer".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Being an ISTJ, I can't completely relate to your thought processes. I will say that flying taught me many things about my thought processes that probably nothing else could. Many aspects of flying are repetitive actions, such as check lists and cockpit flow procedure (S). On the other hand, understanding and interpreting weather is quite fluid (N?). I can say that I have never been bored while flying in the left or right front seats. I suspect that an ENFP, with the will to do it, could probably take an intro flight and progress to being a competent Private Pilot without ever getting bored. But professional flying is a different matter all together. Remember, with respect to boredom and aviation, complacency kills.

Hopefully an ENFP will chime-in.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason that an ENFP, or any other kind of personality cannot become a good pilot.  I encourage you to try.  Take a discovery flight at a local airport and see what you think.